# Powershell with exchange-- How do I append all verbose output to a file

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I am trying to add some logging into my script.  Any advice would be much appreciated. To start out- I'd like to add an error log when something goes amiss.

For instance when a user cannot be found the following error throws:

The operation couldn't be performed because object 'asdfa' couldn't be found on 'HQ-DC-6.domain.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Set-RemoteMailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 47285FC7,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetRemoteMailbox
    + PSComputerName        : hq-cas2.domain.com

==============================

```
$users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content 'C:\Users\test\Documents\Powershell Scripts\OffboardUsers.txt')) {

$tmpname = Get-RemoteMailbox -Identity $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$tmpDisplayName = Get-RemoteMailbox -Identity $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName

Set-RemoteMailbox -Identity $user -Name ("_" + "$tmpname") >> error.log
Set-RemoteMailbox -Identity $user -DisplayName ("_" + "$tmpDisplayName") >> error.log
Set-RemoteMailbox -Identity $user -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true >> error.log

}
```

Comment: I can venture a guess but you don't explain what is wrong about your script. The level of logging you are trying doesn't really match the title of the question. Are you trying to log _everything_ or just some specific lines?

Comment: Hi @Matt, thank you for the quick reply.  If possible, i'd like to log only errors for now.

For instance this error throws when a user does not exist: 
 
The operation couldn't be performed because object 'asdfa' couldn't be found on 'HQ-DC-6.domain.com'.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Set-RemoteMailbox], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 47285FC7,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetRemoteMailbox
    + PSComputerName        : hq-cas2.domain.com

Comment: Are the windows event logs out of the question?  You could create your own application specific log.

Answer (score 2):

*This article is completely revised 2017-07-18 as the new [`Log-Entry`](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry) solution replaces the former [`Write-Log`](https://github.com/iRon7/Write-Log) solution which will not be further updated. See also: [Migrating from Write-Log](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry/blob/master/Migrating%20from%20Write-Log.md).*

---

In general, I find that logging is underestimated for Microsoft scripting languages. Not only at design time of a script (or cmdlet) logging comes in handy but when the script gets deployed and something goes wrong you often wish that you had much better logging in place.
That's why I think that scripting languages as PowerShell (as well as its predecessor VBScript) should actually come with a more sophisticated native logging capabilities than what is available now.

### Best practice

Even before PowerShell existed, I had a similar need for a adequate logging function in VBScript. As a matter of fact, some of the concepts I was using for VBScript, I am still using in PowerShell. Meanwhile, I have extended my logging solution with a whole list of improvements and requirements as I expect a log function to be:

- Robust and never cause the actual cmdlet to fail unexpectedly (even
  when e.g. the access to the log file is for some reason denied)
- Simple to invoke and possibly be used as a
  `Write-Host` command replacement
- Resolve all data types and reveal the content
- Capture unexpected native script errors
- Capable to pass-through objects for inline logging to minimize additional code lines
- Have an accurate (10ms) timestamp per entry for performance trouble
  shooting
- Standard capturing troubleshooting information like:

  - Script version
  - PowerShell version
  - When it was ran (process start time)
  - How (parameters) and from where (location) it was ran
- Appended append information to a configurable log file which doesn't grow indefinitely
- Downwards compatible with PowerShell version 2

### Robust

If you want to go for a robust logging solution, you probably want to go with the native Start-Transcript cmdlet but you will probably find out that the  `Start-Transcript` lacks features, like timestamps, that you might expect from a proper logging cmdlet. You could go for a 3rd party solution but this usually means extra installation procedures and dependencies.
So you decide to write it yourself but even the simplest solution where you just write information to a file might already cause an issue in the field: the file might not be accessible. It might even exist but your script is triggered twice and multiple instances run at the same time the log file might be open by one of instances and access is denied from the other instance  (see e.g.: [Powershell Scheduled Tasks conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548283/powershell-scheduled-tasks-conflicts)). And just at this point, logging should actually help you to troubleshoot what is going on as a repetitive trigger might also cause unexpected behavior in the script itself. For this particular example, the solution I present here buffers the output until it is able to write. But there are a lot more traps in writing a logging cmdlet and correctly formatting the output.

## Log-Entry

I have put the whole solution in a [`Log-Entry.ps1` framework](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry/Log-Entry.ps1) consisting out of a  few major parts:

1. A help header - and a `Main` function template with a few examples
2. A `My` object that contains some script - and logging definitions
3. Four functions to control the logging:

   - `Log-Entry` (alias `Log`) to log information and objects
   - `Set-LogFile` (alias `LogFile`) to set the location of the log file
   - `End-Script` (alias `End`) which might be used to nicely close the session
   - `ConvertTo-Text` (alias `CText`) to resolve objects

For the latest [`Log-Entry.ps1`](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry/Log-Entry.ps1) version, see: https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry.

### Usage

Download the above  [`Log-Entry.ps1` framwork](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry/Log-Entry.ps1) and replace the examples in the `Main {}` function with your own script.  Everywhere you would like to display and log information, use the `Log` command (similar to the `Write-Host` command syntax).
Run the script and check the log file at: `%Temp%\<ScriptName>.Log`

### Syntax

For details on the syntax, see: the [readme.md](https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry/readme.md) at https://github.com/iRon7/Log-Entry

**Example**

Here are a few commands that show some of the features of the `Log-Entry` framework:

```
LogFile .\Test.log                  # Redirect the log file location (Optional)
Log -Color Yellow "Examples:"
Log "Several examples that usually aren't displayed by Write-Host:" $NotSet @() @(@()) @(@(), @()) @($Null)
Log -Indent 1 "Note 1: An empty string:" "" "isn't displayed by Log-Entry either (as you usually do not want every comment quoted)."
Log -Indent 2 "In case you want to reveal a (possible) empty string, use -QuoteString:" -NoNewline; Log -QuoteString ""
Log -Indent 1 "Note 2: An empty array embedded in another array:" @(@()) "is flattened by PowerShell (and not Write-Log)."
Log -Indent 2 "To prevent this use a comma in front of the embbed array: " @(,@())
Log "A hashtable:" @{one = 1; two = 2; three = 3}
Log "A recursive hashtable:" @{one = @{one = @{one = 1; two = 2; three = 3}; two = 2; three = 3}; two = 2; three = 3} -Expand -Depth:9
Log "Character array:" "Hallo World".ToCharArray()
Log-Verbose "The following line produces a error which is captured in the log file:"
$File = Log "File:" (Get-ChildItem "C:\NoSuchFile.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
Log-Verbose "The switch -FlushErrors prevents the error being logged:"
$File = Log "File:" (Get-ChildItem "C:\NoSuchFile.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -FlushErrors
Log "Below are two inline log examples (the object preceding the ""?"" is returned):"
$Height = Log "Height:" 3 ? "Inch"
$Width  = Log "Width:"  4 ? "Inch"
Log-Verbose "Or one display/log line spread over multiple code lines:"
Log "Periphery:" -NoNewline
$Periphery = Log (2 * $Height + 2 * $Width) ? -Color Green -NoNewline
Log "Inch"
Log-Debug "Password:" $Password "(This will not be shown and captured unless the common -Debug argument is supplied)"
```

**Display**

The example commands are displayed in the following format:

[image: Display]

**Log file**

The example commands record the following information in the log file:

```
2017-07-13  PowerShell version: 5.1.15063.483, process start: 2017-07-13 15:39:44
15:39:46.75 Log-Entry version: 02.00.01, command line: C:\Users\User\Scripts\Log-Entry\Log-Entry.ps1 
15:39:46.80 Examples:
15:39:46.94 Several examples that usually aren't displayed by Write-Host: $Null @() @() @(@(), @()) @($Null)
15:39:46.95         Note 1: An empty string: isn't displayed by Log-Entry either (as you do not want every comment quoted).
15:39:46.98                 In case you want to reveal a (possible) empty string, use -QuoteString: ""
15:39:47.00         Note 2: An empty array embedded in another array: @() is flattened by PowerShell (and not Write-Log).
15:39:47.01                 To prevent this use a comma in front of the embbed array:  @(@())
15:39:47.05 A hashtable: @{one = 1, three = 3, two = 2}
15:39:47.06 A recursive hashtable: @{
                one = @{
                    one = @{
                        one = 1, 
                        three = 3, 
                        two = 2
                    }, 
                    three = 3, 
                    two = 2
                }, 
                three = 3, 
                two = 2
            }
15:39:47.10 Character array: @(H, a, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, l, d)
15:39:47.11 The following line produces a error which is captured in the log file:
Error at 51,23: Cannot find path 'C:\NoSuchFile.txt' because it does not exist.
15:39:47.15 File: $Null
15:39:47.16 The switch -FlushErrors prevents the error being logged:
15:39:47.17 File: $Null
15:39:47.17 Below are two inline log examples (the object preceding the "?" is returned):
15:39:47.18 Height: 3 Inch
15:39:47.19 Width: 4 Inch
15:39:47.19 Or one display/log line spread over multiple code lines:
15:39:47.20 Periphery: 14 Inch
15:39:47.27 End (Execution time: 00:00:00.5781145, Process time: 00:00:03.1067112)
```

Comment: Wow. Coming into powershell after being spoiled with python's logging, the capability offered was depressing. Googled for something better and stumbled onto this post. Seeing the detailed consideration and thought you've put into this is awesome. It's unreal how new this is too! Here's hoping this catches on like crazy, and eventually Microsoft talks to you about incorporating it into powershell proper. Off to download and try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Write-Log function. That would be the best way in your case I believe.

This function has been written by Jason Wasser:

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Write-Log writes a message to a specified log file with the current time stamp.
.DESCRIPTION
   The Write-Log function is designed to add logging capability to other scripts.
   In addition to writing output and/or verbose you can write to a log file for
   later debugging.
.NOTES
   Created by: Jason Wasser @wasserja
   Modified: 11/24/2015 09:30:19 AM  

   Changelog:
    * Code simplification and clarification - thanks to @juneb_get_help
    * Added documentation.
    * Renamed LogPath parameter to Path to keep it standard - thanks to @JeffHicks
    * Revised the Force switch to work as it should - thanks to @JeffHicks

   To Do:
    * Add error handling if trying to create a log file in a inaccessible location.
    * Add ability to write $Message to $Verbose or $Error pipelines to eliminate
      duplicates.
.PARAMETER Message
   Message is the content that you wish to add to the log file. 
.PARAMETER Path
   The path to the log file to which you would like to write. By default the function will 
   create the path and file if it does not exist. 
.PARAMETER Level
   Specify the criticality of the log information being written to the log (i.e. Error, Warning, Informational)
.PARAMETER NoClobber
   Use NoClobber if you do not wish to overwrite an existing file.
.EXAMPLE
   Write-Log -Message 'Log message' 
   Writes the message to c:\Logs\PowerShellLog.log.
.EXAMPLE
   Write-Log -Message 'Restarting Server.' -Path c:\Logs\Scriptoutput.log
   Writes the content to the specified log file and creates the path and file specified. 
.EXAMPLE
   Write-Log -Message 'Folder does not exist.' -Path c:\Logs\Script.log -Level Error
   Writes the message to the specified log file as an error message, and writes the message to the error pipeline.
.LINK
   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Write-Log-PowerShell-999c32d0
#>
function Write-Log
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias("LogContent")]
        [string]$Message,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Alias('LogPath')]
        [string]$Path='C:\Logs\PowerShellLog.log',

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateSet("Error","Warn","Info")]
        [string]$Level="Info",

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$NoClobber
    )

    Begin
    {
        # Set VerbosePreference to Continue so that verbose messages are displayed.
        $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'
    }
    Process
    {

        # If the file already exists and NoClobber was specified, do not write to the log.
        if ((Test-Path $Path) -AND $NoClobber) {
            Write-Error "Log file $Path already exists, and you specified NoClobber. Either delete the file or specify a different name."
            Return
            }

        # If attempting to write to a log file in a folder/path that doesn't exist create the file including the path.
        elseif (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
            Write-Verbose "Creating $Path."
            $NewLogFile = New-Item $Path -Force -ItemType File
            }

        else {
            # Nothing to see here yet.
            }

        # Format Date for our Log File
        $FormattedDate = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

        # Write message to error, warning, or verbose pipeline and specify $LevelText
        switch ($Level) {
            'Error' {
                Write-Error $Message
                $LevelText = 'ERROR:'
                }
            'Warn' {
                Write-Warning $Message
                $LevelText = 'WARNING:'
                }
            'Info' {
                Write-Verbose $Message
                $LevelText = 'INFO:'
                }
            }

        # Write log entry to $Path
        "$FormattedDate $LevelText $Message" | Out-File -FilePath $Path -Append
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 Write-Log -Message 'Folder does not exist.' -Path c:\Logs\Script.log -Level Error

Write-Log -Message 'Restarting Server.' -Path c:\Logs\Scriptoutput.log
```

Note: You can use a get-help for this function always for all the details.

Hope it helps.