# How to get iterate through json in powershell without being able to specify the value.

Tags: json, powershell

I need to read some information from json in Powershell.  The problem that I am having is that after the "paths" section I cannot specify the next name e.g. what the path is called because it changes. Then after that I need to get the "get" section and then the "parameters" section and finally get the name and the required fields there.

I can get the hostname by using `$info.host` and the paths like `$info.paths`.  Then I get the individual path names by looping through the path's to get each name like this.

```
foreach($item in $pName)
{
    $item  
}
```

But then that is as far as I can get I tried using $item.childItem but it doesn't work.  Is there anyway to use something like $item.paths.childItems[$1].get.parameters and then get the name and the required field values?

The json looks like this:

```
{
"swagger": "2.0",
"info": {
"version": "v1",
"title": "Requirements.API"
},
"host": "replica.net",
"schemes": [
"http"
],
"paths": {
"/": {
"get": {
"tags": [
"Alive"
],
"operationId": "Alive_Get",
"consumes": [],
"produces": [
"application/json",
"text/json",
"application/xml",
"text/xml"
],
"responses": {
"200": {
"description": "OK",
"schema": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/Object"
}
}
},
"deprecated": false
}
},
"/requirements/email-docs": {
"get": {
"tags": [
"CustomerRequirement"
],
"operationId": "",
"consumes": [],
"produces": [
"application/json",
"text/json",
"application/xml",
"text/xml"
],
"parameters": [
{
"name": "name",
"in": "query",
"required": true,
"type": "integer",
"format": "int32"
}
],
"responses": {
"200": {
"description": "OK",
"schema": {
"type": "array",
"items": {
"$ref": "#/definitions/UploadResponse"
}
}
}
},
"deprecated": false
}
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using this:

```
  for($i=0;$i-lt$pName.Count;$i++)
            {
                $test | Select -ExpandProperty paths | select -ExpandProperty $pName[$i] | select -ExpandProperty get

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file is not clearly formatted and misses some closing parentheses.
Nevertheless, after closing the JSON file and read it into PowerShell (`ConvertFrom-Json`), your PowerShell object looks like this (using [PSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139552/save-hash-table-in-powershell-object-notation-pson/24854277#24854277) or [Write-Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860911/powershell-with-exchange-how-do-i-append-all-verbose-output-to-a-file/44265303#44265303)):

```
{
        swagger: "2.0",
        info: {
                version: "v1",
                title: "Requirements.API"
        },
        host: "replica.net",
        schemes: @(
                "http"
        ),
        paths: {
                /: {
                        get: {
                                tags: @(
                                        "Alive"
                                ),
                                operationId: "Alive_Get",
                                consumes: @(),
                                produces: @(
                                        "application/json",
                                        "text/json",
                                        "application/xml",
                                        "text/xml"
                                ),
                                responses: {
                                        200: {
                                                description: "OK",
                                                schema: {
                                                        $ref: "#/definitions/Object"
                                                }
                                        }
                                },
                                deprecated: $False
                        }
                },
                /requirements/email-docs: {
                        get: {
                                tags: @(
                                        "CustomerRequirement"
                                ),
                                operationId: "",
                                consumes: @(),
                                produces: @(
                                        "application/json",
                                        "text/json",
                                        "application/xml",
                                        "text/xml"
                                ),
                                parameters: @(
                                        {
                                                name: "name",
                                                in: "query",
                                                required: $True,
                                                type: "integer",
                                                format: "int32"
                                        }
                                ),
                                responses: {
                                        200: {
                                                description: "OK",
                                                schema: {
                                                        type: "array",
                                                        items: {
                                                                $ref: "#/definitions/UploadResponse"
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                },
                                deprecated: $False
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

So I guess the properties/values where you looking for are:

```
$Item.paths.PSObject.Properties | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```