# Add logging quickly to an existing set of powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, logging

I've got a collection of powershell scripts, some of which call others. Some of these subscripts can also be called on their own as needed. How can I quickly add logging to all of the scripts so that any script invocation results in a log file for later examination?

There are a number of questions dealing with logging with some great answers, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860911/powershell-with-exchange-how-do-i-append-all-verbose-output-to-a-file/44265303). But I wanted to see what we could come up with that:

- required minimal touching of the existing powershell files
- automatically dealt with script A.ps1 calling script B.ps1. If you call
  A.ps1, A.ps1 needs to start and finish the logging. But if you call B.ps1
  directly, B.ps1 does.

I came up with my answer below, and wanted to share and see if there were other ideas on how to approach this, or suggestions for improvement on my answer.

Comment: [or you can turn on automatic script logging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/06/09/powershell-the-blue-team/)

Answer (score 2):

The support code I write (further down) allows for just adding the following to each ps1 file. It automatically gives me logging regardless of if a script is called at top-level or by another script:

```
#any params for script
. "$PSScriptRoot\ps_support.ps1"
StartTranscriptIfAppropriate
try
{
#all of the original script
}
finally
{
ConditionalStopTranscript
}
```

The code that powers this is in ps_support.ps1, sitting next to my collection of powershell files that need logging. It uses Get-Variable and Set-Variable to manipulate a couple variables at the caller's scope level:

- `Logging__TranscriptStarted` is normal so sub-scopes can see that
  logging is already happening and not try to start it again.
- `Logging__TranscriptStartedPrivate` is private so a scope can know if
  it is responsible for stopping the logging.

Here is ps_support.ps1:

```
Set-Variable -name TranscriptStartedPropertyName -opt ReadOnly -value 'Logging__TranscriptStarted'
Set-Variable -name TranscriptStartedPrivatePropertyName -opt ReadOnly -value 'Logging__TranscriptStartedPrivate'

function StartTranscriptIfAppropriate
{
    $transcriptStarted = [bool](Get-Variable -name $TranscriptStartedPropertyName -ErrorAction Ignore)
    if (-not $transcriptStarted)
    {
        $callstack = get-pscallstack
        $fullPath = $callstack[$callstack.count-2].ScriptName
        $name = Split-Path -Path $fullPath -Leaf
        $directory = Split-Path -Path $fullPath
        $logDirectory = [IO.Path]::GetFullPath("$directory\..\scripts_logs")
        md -force $logDirectory | out-null
        $logFinalPath = "$logDirectory\$(Get-Date -Format o | foreach {$_ -replace ":", "."})_$name.log"
        Set-Variable -scope 1 -name $TranscriptStartedPropertyName -value $True
        Set-Variable -scope 1 -option private -name $TranscriptStartedPrivatePropertyName -value $True
        Start-Transcript $logFinalPath | Write-Host
    }
    $immediateCallerPath = Get-Variable -scope 1 -name PSCommandPath -ValueOnly
    Write-Host "Starting script at $immediateCallerPath"
}

function ConditionalStopTranscript
{
    $immediateCallerPath = Get-Variable -scope 1 -name PSCommandPath -ValueOnly
    Write-Host "Stopping script at $immediateCallerPath"
    $transcriptStartedByMe = [bool](Get-Variable -scope 1 -name $TranscriptStartedPrivatePropertyName -ErrorAction Ignore)
    if ($transcriptStartedByMe)
    {
        Stop-Transcript | Write-Host
    }
}
```